# Antd Datepicker in Electron - Cannot read property 'year' of null

Tags: reactjs, webpack, electron, momentjs, antd

I'm developing an electron application that's built w/ React, antd (as a primary component library), and packaged with webpack.

I'm running into an extremely weird issue where, upon packaging the electron application using a packaging script (`webpack --config webpack.build.config.js`) - the antd datepicker component crashes on click (produces the following error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ef0F9.jpg). I've checked that everything in the versions is the same, including all of the dependencies and browser versions.

I know I'm not providing a lot of detail, but was wondering if anyone has faced any remotely similar issues before? Really slamming my head against the wall here, since I'm not really sure how to even debug this (going through the stack trace really provides no clues, other than this code that seems to originate from the moment.js library - https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrDcW.jpg - worth noting that `e` is null, wheras in the dev version of the application, `e` is the date selected by the datepicker).

Thank you all!

Comment: I have the same problem as you. Any luck solving it?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using electron to build a binary file.

DateRange would work on development, but not on production.

After a lot of fooling around, the culprit was babili webpack pllugin on webpack.config.
To fix it:
before:

```
optimization: {
      minimizer: [
        new UglifyJsPlugin(),
        new TerserPlugin(),
        new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin()
      ],
...
}
```

After:

```
optimization: {
      minimizer: [
        new UglifyJsPlugin(),
        new TerserPlugin(),
        new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin()
      ],
...
}
```